# Safely powering Dell laptop from external Li-ion battery with a 11.1V/19.5V step-up converter

Tags: boost, zener, fuses, laptop, step-up

I need to build a power-bank type device for my Dell Latitude 6530 laptop (19.5V, 90W nominal power input).

I have 12 Li-ion 3.7V, 3.35Ah (18650-type) cells, 3S4P configuration (11.1V total output). I also have a 200W, 6-35V/9-55V step-up converter, together with all the necessary wiring and plugs.

I connected the battery to the converter, set-up the right voltage, then connected the plug to the laptop. It worked like a charm, ie. the computer was not draining the battery (I knew and accepted it won't be charging, due to Dell's policy on foreign power adaptors). Everything was working fine until I needed to replace the battery on the boost's input. Apparently right after connecting the new one output voltage has surged far beyond the safety limit of my laptop. I heard a quiet click sound and found the computer damaged. It can only work on batteries now, no more charging, servicing required.

Lesson learnt, I want to avoid this kind of issues in a future. I consider adding a 20V Zener diode on the converter's output (typical cathode-plus setup). To protect a converter itself from over-current I think of adding a fuse between the output and Zener. I believe using a Zener has an additional benefit of protecting the converter in case of inducing a high voltage on the receiver (no matter the polarization).

I'm a passionate, not an expert in electronics - this is the first step-up converted I'm handling. The question is whether the above solution makes any sense and can effectively protect the devices? Are there Zener diodes capable of handling this output power (provided that I won't be increasing the output voltage)? What other measures I can (or should) take to prevent damaging my laptop (or any other receiver) again?

Unfortunately I don't have any schema of the converter itself, but I can try to get it if necessary.

EDIT #1 (2020-04-21 13:17 CEST):
As requested, here's the schema:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTSMQi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It would definitely help if you draw a simple schematic of how you plan to implement this protection. You can even draw it on a piece of paper and upload a photo of it. Also, a photo of your setup could help.

Comment: @EdinFifić - here it is, I've just discovered the built-in diagram editor. Zener's type and fuse's max current are just a shot.

Answer (score 1):

6A 20V will blow any common Zener diode very quickly, and your design gives no indication that it has blown.  The diode may well blow before the fuse.

Adding a small dummy load to the output of the boost converter may make it more stable if the laptop is not yet connected.  Check the manufacturer's data sheet to see if they specify a minimum load.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 12 Li-Ion cells, instead going the complicated and less efficient route, I would use 5 cells in series instead, which would provide anywhere from around 18V to 21V, and this should be tolerable by most, if not all, laptops with a 19V-rated input.
With 5 cells in series, their load current will be almost cut in half because the laptop's DC-DC converter(s) will pull the watts needed, and because there will be no loss from the boost converter (about 10% or so).
You could make 2 strings of 5 cells in series and connect them together in parallel so that they last longer, or your could leave them separate so that you charge one while the other one is being used.

Comment: I considered a simple setup you propose, but chosen to use a step-up converter because: a) I ocassionaly need to charge batteries from a 12V source; b) the nominal voltage of the 5S battery is only 18.5V, and minimal permitted for the cells is ~ 14.5V (I have a BMS to protect from a deep discharge), and I would like to use it to the full; c) cells' max current reportedly degrades with discharging, not sure about the exact values, this is why I use a 4P setup; d) the adaptor built should be universal - I want to ocassionaly connect other batteries.